# Why $0^{x}$ Can't be Written as $e^{x\times ln{0}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Usually $a^{b}$ can be written as $e^{b\times ln{a}}$, for example:

$x^{0}=e^{0\times ln{x}} = e^{0}=1$ where $x \neq 0$

In case of  $0^{x}=?0$, we get $e^{x\times ln{0}}$ and since $ln{0}$ is not defined, I am not sure about this rule.

Also as stated in comments, consider $0^{-1}$.

Why this is not applicable to $0^{x}$?

Is this rule always true?

Comment: What is the natural log of zero?

Comment: $ln 0$ is not defined.

Comment: @JMoravitz It is undefined, but is the rule correct?

Comment: $a^b$ for nonzero $a$ is defined to be $e^{b\times \ln a}$, absolutely.  For $a=0$ we be more careful and we say that $0^x$ is equal to zero for all positive real $x$.  Now... as for $0^0$, we be even more careful still.  This last one will have a value dependent on context and what you define it to be.  See elsewhere on this site for more information, but it is common to let $0^0$ equal $1$ for convenience.  For negative $x$, it remains undefined.

Comment: IF $a^x = \exp(x\log a)$ is a definition, then of course it is correct.  But if you have in mind some other definition, then you will need to check whether it obeys this.

Comment: @JMoravitz ... I disagree that $0^x$ is zero for all nonzero $x$.  For example, consider $0^{-1}$.

Comment: @GEdgar fair enough., for all *positive* $x$ then, and negative remains undefined.

Answer (score 2):

When rearranging an expression, you have to consider whether your rearrangement changes the domain (set of permissible inputs). For example, take the function $f(x)=x$, which we could rearrange to $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x}$. This rearrangement gives exactly the same values as the original expression but it isn't defined at $0$, since division by $0$ is undefined.

Your example is exactly the same. The expression $a^b$ is well defined for three cases*:

- $a<0$ and $b$ is a rational number**
- $a=0,\ b\neq0$
- $a>0$ and $b$ is any number

While it is true that $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$ for all points where $e^{b\ln a}$ is well defined, that *isn't* all points in the domain of $a^b$. Clearly $\ln a$ is only defined for $a>0$ so the domain changed when you rearranged the function and the rearrangement $0^x=e^{x\ln0}$ is undefined.

---

* Ignoring complex numbers.
** Except those with even denominators.

Answer (score 1):

The question is obviously very heuristic, but the following is a heuristic answer.

$ln0=-\infty$, therefore $e^{xln0}=e^{-\infty}=0$ for $x\gt 0$ and $=e^{\infty}=\infty$ for $x\lt 0$

$0^0$ remains indeterminate.